# SQL Server Full Text search for numeric string with commas

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, full-text-search

I have a full-text indexed nvarchar(max) column on a SQL Server 2012 install.  If one row of the column has 'blah blah $1,234,567 blah blah' as data. When I run the following queries, the ones that return the row are shown:

```
SELECT ftext FROM dbo.Test WHERE Contains([ftext], '"1,234,567*"') --true
SELECT ftext FROM dbo.Test WHERE Contains([ftext], '"1234567*"') --true
SELECT ftext FROM dbo.Test WHERE Contains([ftext], '"1,234*"') --true
SELECT ftext FROM dbo.Test WHERE Contains([ftext], '"1234*"') --true
SELECT ftext FROM dbo.Test WHERE Contains([ftext], '"1,234,5*"') --false
SELECT ftext FROM dbo.Test WHERE Contains([ftext], '"12345*"') --true
SELECT ftext FROM dbo.Test WHERE Contains([ftext], '"1,234,56*"') --false
SELECT ftext FROM dbo.Test WHERE Contains([ftext], '"123456*"') --true
```

At first I just assumed the comma was treated as noise, but that doesn't seem to be the case as "1,234,567*" and "1,234*" return a result while "1,234,5*" and "1,234,56*" do not.  Why is this?

Comment: Are you using a stop word list? (The system stop word list is used by default.) If so, try setting it to off, reindex, and see if this problem still happens. I suspect the stop word list is causing some weird behavior.

Comment: I ran "ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON dbo.Test SET STOPLIST = OFF" and then repopulated the full text index and still am getting the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is due to a combination of how numeric values are treated and how the word breaker is applied to the search term. **In short, if the text looks like a number *without the wildcard* then it is treated like a number, otherwise it is treated like a string.**

When searching on a valid number with commas, the full text engine will treat it as both a string and a number. You can see this in action by using [sys.dm_fts_parser](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280463(v=sql.100).aspx) which is used by the engine to parse the search string. For example, here are the results of `SELECT display_term FROM sys.dm_fts_parser (' "1,234,567*" ', 1033, 0, 0)`:

```
display_term
---------------------
1,234,567      <-- string
nn1234567      <-- number
```

I'm a little unsure of how `1,234,567` is stored in the full text index -- it will be one of the above values listed above or both -- but regardless, it's easy to see how `"1,234,567*"` will find a match in the index.

Now let's try `"1,234,56*"`. The results of `SELECT * FROM sys.dm_fts_parser (' "1,234,56*" ', 1033, 0, 0)` are:

```
display_term
---------------------
1
nn1
234
nn234
56
nn56
```

Whoa, what happened? Well, `1,234,56` is not a valid number, so it is treated like a string. Thus it is split by the commas and the individual values (`1`, `234`, `56`) are identified as being strings or numbers. It's the same as if you searched for `"1" AND "234" AND "56*"`.

Some ideas for working around this behavior:

- Use a LIKE query instead `SELECT ftext FROM dbo.Test WHERE [ftext] LIKE '1,234,56%'`
- Pre-process the search string to remove commas from numbers.